# Modal not appearing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am working on [Stardom](http://themeforest.net/item/stardom-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-theme/6534568) admin template. I am working on `Modals`, and the problem is that my screen fades, and a modal is shown but it's inactive, and I can't perform any action on it.

My code:

```html
<a href="#" class="tableLinks" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alertModal">
  <i class="fa fa-eye" title="Make inactive"></i>
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="alertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;     </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Are you sure that's what you want?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="margin-bottom-lg"> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </p>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-gradient margin-right-sm" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Of course I am
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-gradient" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No nevermind
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how the modal appears on my screen:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another modal active on the page?

Comment: yes there is no other modal on the page

Comment: It's strange, because your code alone is working well http://jsbin.com/lakacari/1

Comment: yeah i tried that too, but there is no other modal on that page

Comment: Can you post all the code of your page?

Comment: i posted all the code from page. one row of table

Comment: what is your css - looks liek there might be a z index issue